# Reading a single character from a file returns -9 error value

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I develop the following code to open an input file named `in.put` and read a single character from it. But `gdb` debugger shows reading a single character returns `-9` at `eax` register. The location of the read-error is shown on the code. I couldn't figure out what I'm missing, does anybody know:

```
section .data   ;initialized data

;input file
input           db      'in.put'
inputhandle:    dd      0x00    ;place-holder for input file handle

section .bss    ;uninitialized data

;prepare memory location for reading a character on file
charbuff:       resb    0x01

section .text   ;instructions
global _start
_start:

    ;open file at read-write permission
    mov ecx, 1          ;read-write
    mov ebx, input      ;file name pointer
    mov eax, 5          ;open
    int 0x80

    ;check if open is good
    cmp eax, 0
    jle end                     ;if eax<=0 , jump end
    mov [inputhandle], eax      ;store returned file handle

    ;read a character on file
    mov edx, 0x01               ;length of signle-character memory location = 0x01
    mov ecx, charbuff           ;pointer to single-character memory location
    mov ebx, [inputhandle]      ;file handle
    mov eax, 3                  ;system read
    int 0x80
    ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ;at this point, debugger shows
    ;the returned value in eax is -9
    ;I'm not sure why
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ;

end:
    ;close file
    mov ebx, [inputhandle]              ;file handle
    mov eax, 6                          ;system close
    int 0x80

    ; exit
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

Comment: Read/Write is 2 not 1 (1 is Write Only) and you should NUL terminate your file name so use `input           db      'in.put', 0`

Comment: @MichaelPetch That was it. My problem is solved now. Thanks.

Comment: `strace ./my-program` is an easier way to debug system calls.  It decodes the args and return values into symbolic constants, using C syntax.

Comment: Also, in Linux, the BSS is guaranteed to contain zeros at process startup.  It's not exactly uninitialized; you can and should use it for static arrays that need to be zero-filled, not just for things where the initial contents don't matter.